# How delete all files in a folder except last 5 items with Python

Tags: python, file, delete-file

I am looking for a way how to clean a folder from files, except last newest five items with Python.

I am quite new to Python, so I was able to keep the last one only with `max()` function, but I am not able to find out how to keep 5 last files.

Does anyone have similar issue?

Thank you for any idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

User os.listdir to get the name of the files. As this returns an iterator you can easily sort the way you want in python itself. then use list indexing to keep the last five ones.

then use os.remove to remove the files

```
import os
for filename in sorted(os.listdir("foldername"))[:-5]:
    filename_relPath = os.path.join("foldername",filename)
    os.remove(filename_relPath)
```

Comment: I want to sort filenames based on last modification time instead of filename sorting alphabetical. I think it sorts as per filename alphabetically and not recent one. Please suggest as per last modification time and keeping recent 5 in python 2.7

Answer (score 3):

At Python standard library level, `os.scandir` retrieves both the file name and its attributes. It is then easy to sort the files according to their modification time:

```
filenames = [entry.name for entry in sorted(os.scandir(path),
                                            key=lambda x: x.stat().st_mtime, reverse=True)]
```

Will return a list of all filenames in `path` folder sorted from newest to oldest. You can then iterate on `filenames[5:]` to remove all the files except the 5 newest ones.

Comment: I want to delete further files with .log extension

Comment: What is entry. Name

Comment: how to delete files with a particular pattern, say *.log?

Answer (score 1):

you can try with this if you are on linux:

```py
import os

directory = /path/to/directory

os.system("cd " + directory + " ls -t1 | tail -n +5 | xargs rm -r")
```

you can try with this if you are on windows:

```py
import os

directory = /path/to/directory

os.system('for /r "skip=5 delims=" %%a in ("dir ' + directory + ' ") do echo del /f "%%a"')
```

or just run this on cmd:

```
for /r "skip=5 delims=" %%a in ('dir /path/to/folder') do echo del /f "%%a"
```

Comment: I am unfortunately on Windows

Comment: how about `head -4` instead of `tail -n +5` ?